# how to submit multiple entries in database table using laravel?

Tags: laravel

I am beginner at laravel and i want to add multiple record into database table and I have a returned request below  but I have no idea how to submit data into table how can I make logic in controller Does anyone have an idea how to to do that please help me thanks.
**Database table**

```
    projectissue table  

     Id  | task  | date| project_id
```

**Controller**

```
         public function issuesUpdate(Request $request,Project $project)
         {


              return redirect()->route('project');
         }
```

**return $request**

```
               {
  "_token": "S6typbw0hywPqaUdxCTqWeJNieyl3VieQhCHqDZ7",
    project_id=42;
  "date": [
    "2020-07-06",
    "2020-07-22",
    "2020-07-11"
  ],
  "issue": [
    "dsfsdfsdfsdf",
    "dsfsdfsdfsdf",
    "dsfsdfsdfsdf"
  ]
}
```

**Route**

```
  Route::post('/projects/{project}/issues/update', "ProjectController@issuesUpdate")- 
  >name('project.issues.update');
```

**Html view**

```
     <form action="{{ route('project.issues.update',[$project->id])}}" method="POST">
      @csrf    
      <div class="portlet">
        <div class="portlet-heading bg-light-theme">
          <h3 class="portlet-title">
            <span class="ti-user mr-2">
            </span>Add Issues
          </h3>
          <div class="portlet-widgets">
            <span class="divider">
            </span>
            <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-white waves-effect btn-rounded">
              <span class="btn-label">
                <i class="fa fa-save">
                </i>
              </span> Save
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="clearfix">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="bg-inverse" class="panel-collapse collapse show" style="">
          <div class="portlet-body">
            <div class="card-box">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 mt20">
                  <div class="addMore">
                    <div class="addmore_cont">
                      <div class="addMore_btn">
                       
                        <div class="mt12 pull-right">
                          <button type="button" title="Add More" class="btn btn-success waves-effect waves-light btn-sm add_more" data-key="">
                            <i class="fa fa-plus">
                            </i>
                          </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row addmore_issues">
                          <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="row">
                              <div class="col-md-5">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                  <input required type="date" value="" name="date[]" class="form-control"
                                         aria-describedby="emailHelp" >
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="col-md-5">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                  <input required type="text" value="" name="issue[]" class="form-control"
                                     aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="task...">
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="col-md-1 mt12">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger waves-effect waves-light btn-sm delete">
                                  <i
                                     class="fa fa-times">
                                  </i>
                                </button>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to read the documentation first: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent. The documentation is written very well. Don't forget to validate the data using form requests (recommended way if you ask me): https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#form-request-validation

I'll give you a head start:

```php
class YourFormRequest
{
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'date'    => ['required', 'array'],
            'date.*'  => ['required', 'date'],
            'issue'   => ['required', 'date'],
            'issue.*' => ['required', 'string'],
        ];
    }
}

class SomeController
{
    public function issuesUpdate(YourFormRequest $request)
    {
        foreach ($request->post('date') as $i => $value) {
            ProjectIssue::insert([
                'attribute' => $request->post(),
            ]);
        }

        return redirect()->route('project');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$dates = request('date');
$issues = request('issue');

for($i = 0; $i < count($issues); $i++)
{

    $issue = new ProjectIssue();
    $issue->task = $issues[$i];
    $issue->date = $dates[$i];
    $issue->project_id = //however you're getting your project id to the controller;
    if($issue->save()){
       continue;
    } else {
      //process error the way you want
    }


}
```

so what my code is doing is storing the request arrays in a variable and looping through the amount of issues that your form submitted. for each issue that is there, it creates a new entry in the table and then goes on to the next one. I'm making a few assumptions in the way I named things, but it should be enough to get you started.